# Creating a new user and its role using phpmyadmin

Tags: php, magento, magento-layout-xml, magento-go

I am new to **Magento**. **I want to create a new user and its role using phpmyadmin** as I don't have access to my admin account, I dont know why it is so? I think anything might go wrong from my side. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Any help will be heartly appreciated.

Comment: i think you need more tags

Comment: means?? I am not getting it @Claudiu

Answer (score 0):

You can create the user if you go in `phpmyadmin`. Search for table `admin_user` and in the right you have insert. Insert a new line. Didn't test it, but it should work.

Comment: Yes, I did it @claudiu except with that I created admin_role too But that didn't work for me. Could you sugeest anything more???